# can't play this video VideoView from openload

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

I uploaded my video to **openload**, so I could create **URL** 
then I used this URL as **URI** to **VideoView** but it shows: "**can't play this video**"
I tried this way with VideoView & **SurfaceView** and the result once

***XML***:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="playVideo" />
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
```

***playVideo Method:***

```
public void playVideo(View view) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your video url must end with file extension

For example, mydomain.com/sample.mp4

Comment: Here's my URL "https://openload.co/f/60Ds4LN_hoA/1_-_Thinking_Like_a_Programmer.mp4"
it's valid but doesn't work. if you know another server or other media players I can use so it would be better.